# MySQL select inner join and union

Tags: mysql, sql, union, inner-join

I have this two tables. I have current player id_player, I want to select all games from this player (id_player) and his opponents info. Current player and opponent player are connected with same id_game.  or

[image: tables]

```
table game:`id_game` (...)
table game_player:`id_game_player, id_player, id_game`(...)
```

> "give me all separate game info from current player and his opponent
>   and join info for their game (grouped by game)"

result as:

```
      +---player game info
game1 |
      +---opponent game info

      +---player game info
game2 |
      +---opponent1 game info

      +---player game info
game2 |
      +---opponent2 game info
```

Can anyone provide me MySQL solution?

Thanks

---

EDIT:
I try with this code but I'm not sure this is fastest way (WHERE IN) and is there any way to group results like above?

```
SELECT * FROM game_player
    JOIN `game` ON game.id_game = game_player.id_game
    WHERE game_player.id_game
    IN (
    SELECT game_player.id_game
    FROM `game_player`
    WHERE game_player.id_player =2)
```

Comment: Where is the the game info?

Comment: "game info" mean all other fields in table *

Comment: The question wording _"give me all separate game info..."_ makes this sound strongly of an assignment question. Can you post your efforts so far?

Comment: I see only one `player_id` where is the other oponenent player_id for each game?

Comment: opponent player_id is the other player with same id_game

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*give this a try*

```
SET @player_ID = 0;                  -- <<== the playerID
SELECT  a.*, b.*, 'player' Status         -- this is the first part of the union
FROM    game a                            -- which gets all the game of
        INNER JOIN game_player b          -- the selected player and its info
            ON a.id_game = b.id_game
WHERE   id_player = @player_ID 
UNION ALL
SELECT  d.*, c.*, 'opponent' status
FROM    game_player c
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  a.*
            FROM    game aa
                    INNER JOIN game_player bb
                        ON aa.id_game = bb.id_game
            WHERE   bb.id_player = @player_ID
        ) d ON c.id_game = d.id_game AND c.id_player <> @player_ID
ORDER   BY id_game, status
```